# Почтовый сервер

Tags: windows, linux

Кто может какой посоветовать почтовый сервер на 250 компов?

Comment: Так под винду всё-таки или под линух? Забавно видеть оба тега сразу :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опыт показал: **postfix** и **exim** под Линух или **MS EXCHANGE** под Винду. Альтернатив почти нет.

Лучше собирать связки под Линух - проблем нет. Один раз настроил и забыл. Я работаю в провайдерской конторе, у нас около 2000 ящиков активных - мы уже пароль рутовый забыли от этого сервера. Шутка конечно, но в каждой шутке есть доля шутки. :)

Мой выбор: **linux(CentOS)+postfix+dovecot+PostgreSQL+postgrey+clamav+SpamAssassin** (три последних опционально)

после многих вариаций остановились на этой связке.

Comment: вопросец-то наверное "РутКодный"

Answer (score 2):

Самый лучший вариант - это заплатить за хостинг почтового сервера. Дешевле выйдет. Вариант, предложенный FoxManiac, отлично работает, но только при условии, что систему настраивал хороший специалист. Да и рутовый пароль забывать все же не стоит. Никогда нельзя заранее сказать, в какой момент он понадобится.

Comment: подпишусь под каждым словом :)

Answer (score 0):

Если под линукс - то тут смотрите, что есть в репозитариях. А потом уже из этого выбирайте.
А вот под виндовс на 250 компов я бы порекомендовал посмотреть на http://courierms.narod.ru/ - раньше, когда нужно было отлаживать программы для работы с почтой - самое оно.